# npm install error in laravel 5.6 with fresh installation

Tags: node.js, laravel, npm, laravel-5.6

I get the following error while running `npm install` on a fresh `laravel 5.6` installation on `windows 7 32 bit`, `npm version 5.7.1`, `node v9.5.0`

> npm ERR! path
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\2018\thehealthsearch\node_modules\node-sass\node_modules\har-validator\bin\har-validator
>       npm ERR! code ENOENT
>       npm ERR! errno -4058
>       npm ERR! syscall chmod
>       npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, chmod 'D:\xampp\htdocs\2018\thehealthsearch\node_modules\node-sass\no
>       de_modules\har-validator\bin\har-validator'
>       npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
>       npm ERR! enoent
>
> ```
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
> npm ERR!     C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-03-14T05_58_42_171Z-debug.log
> ```

How to resolve this?

**EDIT :**

My Package.json file

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
        "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.18",
        "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
        "popper.js": "^1.12",
        "cross-env": "^5.1",
        "jquery": "^3.2",
        "laravel-mix": "^2.0",
        "lodash": "^4.17.4",
        "vue": "^2.5.16"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "har-validator": "^5.1.0",
        "yarn": "^0.16.1"
    }
}
```

Comment: post ur composer json file too

Comment: @laravellevaral Do you mean package.json? i updated above

Comment: Try this commands line by line: `npm cache clean`, 
`npm install -g gulp bower`, 
`npm install`, 
`bower install`, 
`gulp & gulp watch`

Comment: @HirenGohel Ah! That works! You saved my day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to try this commands line by line:

```
npm cache clean           
npm install -g gulp bower 
npm install               
bower install             
gulp & gulp watch
```

This commands do:

1. for cleaning a cache of npm
2. installs gulp bower globally
3. installs npm
4. installs bower
5. for mixing all js and css and watch on all changes of css & js

Hope this will helps you and fixed your issue!

Comment: just add npm cache clean --force as npm cache clean didn't work for me and i used powershell as administrator as there were restrictons on the command prompt for the user im logged into

Comment: Sorry for late reply! So, have you got any errors or fixed it now?

Comment: It is fixed. Thank you so much for helping!

Comment: wait wait wait......if we're using laravel mix and such why are we switching from that to bower and gulp. That is not the laravel way at all.

Comment: @BillGarrison: this answer is too old and may be not worked for newer laravel version, please make sure the version and whats the exact issue is :)

Comment: I state all the versions of everything im using in my question.